# How can I deal two class classification problem when one class have only .02 percent of all data sample?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, unbalanced-classes

How can I deal two class classification problem when one class have only .02 percent  of all data sample?  I have total 6000 data sample and this is two class classification problem. one class having only 100  positive group and rest of data point resides on negative group? How can I handle in R?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the things you have tried until?

Comment: What about undersampling majority class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use F-score, it is specifically intended for classifying skewed classes. You can read about on [wiki: Precision and Recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall)

Answer (score 0):

You can use pretty much any discriminant analysis approach that lets you change a 'cutoff' value to control the false positive vs false negative rate.  So, at least linear, quadratic, nearest neighbors, logistic regression.  Depending on the software, even neural nets, CART, etc.  You have to be able to set a LOSS function.  You can either look at the costs of the two types of errors and use the corresponding loss function, or else you can try lots of cutoff values and see what error rates you get (this is what you do when you derive an ROC curve).  Then look for the model that gives you the correct balance of false negative and false positive rates.

This is usually the best approach, because the error of calling a positive group member a negative group member might be very different from the cost of the error of calling a negative group member a positive group member.